# do-dist-upgrade from ubuntu 14 LTS to 16 LTS - What are these warning about not installed software?

Tags: ubuntu

I am attempting to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16 LTS.

I have a specific question to ask.

I encountered some warnings regarding 'no candidate ver'; I have removed unnecessary lines.

```
No candidate ver:  apache2.2-common

No candidate ver:  mysql-server-5.5
```

I am actually running mysql server 5.6 and apache 2.4.

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.33, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Apr  3 2019 18:04:25
```

Why is ubuntu warning me about mysql-server-5.5 and apache2.2-common?
What should I do in this case?

Comment: uninstall; upgrade; install

Comment: I cannot install mysql-server-5.5. I haven't it ! I have mysql-server-5.6

Comment: What's the point of sticking to the old unsupported vulnerable release?

Comment: This doen't answer my question. If I already have the 5.6, what does it mean that 5.5 is not available? Why is the OS looking for 5.5? I haven't it no more!

Comment: Anyway I cannot jump to latest LTS and cannot move the app. It's not my decision. So I'm trying to do little upgrades to be able to jump to next LTS. And redo until I reach latest LTS. Sorry, but my company has a zero-courage policy